# How to restart app again when user exit from application

Tags: android, application-restart

Hi in my code when user press back button from mainactivity he/she exit from the application but problem is when user again press application icon it resume the mainactivity where i left it..... i want to restart my app again when user click on application icon. Thanks in advance

```
///exit from app by pressing back button
 public void onBackPressed() {
       Log.i("HA", "Finishing");
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
       intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
       intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       startActivity(intent);
     }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There are three options:

1.You can override onResume() and put whatever is there in your onCreate() method inside it to do fresh restart everytime..

2.You can override onPause and kill the activity

> onStop(); onCreate(getIntent().getExtras());

3.The best approach:
Alternatively you can also use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY so that your activity is restarted everytime.

> public static final int FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
>
> Added in API level 1 If set, the new activity is not kept in the
>   history stack. As soon as the user navigates away from it, the
>   activity is finished. This may also be set with the noHistory
>   attribute.
>
> Constant Value: 1073741824 (0x40000000)

Answer (score 0):

You need this

```
public static final int FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
```

Added in API level 11
If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will cause any existing task that would be associated with the activity to be cleared before the activity is started. That is, the activity becomes the new root of an otherwise empty task, and any old activities are finished.

You should look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)